# Axios returns cached data

Tags: reactjs, caching, axios, fetch

When making a fetch request to my dev.to profile (fetching my publishes aka posts), axios returns an array of old data. what I mean by that is, I recently created a new post on dev.to, in total i now have 3 posts. when making a request to fetch all the posts using axios, it returns only 2.

Fetching:

```js
useEffect(() => {
    axios
      .get('https://dev.to/api/articles?username=timbogdanov', {
        method: 'POST', // *GET, POST, PUT, DELETE, etc.
        mode: 'cors', // no-cors, *cors, same-origin
        cache: 'no-cache', // *default, no-cache, reload, force-cache, only-if-cached
        credentials: 'same-origin', // include, *same-origin, omit
        headers: {
          'Content-Type': 'application/json',
        },
      })
      .then((res) => {
        setPosts(res.data);
      });
  }, []);
```

Data I get back:
https://puu.sh/Gu3lr/61725cc204.png

Data i **should** get back:

> https://dev.to/api/articles?username=timbogdanov

Comment: Have you checked your browser network tab? Is there a request to dev.to? What it returns?

Comment: https://puu.sh/Gu4zo/9b579a05c1.png

Comment: Viktor if you look at https://timbogdanov.me and https://portfolio-git-master.timbogdanov.vercel.app/ you will notice that one of them has 3 articles while the other has 2. both are fetching the same exact thing

Comment: @TimBogdanov Hi, may I know how u solved this? am facing the same issue now